# ExecuteScalar returns value is not suitable

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I use Enterprise Library and I have one problem:

```
string sql = " 
               UPDATE StackOverflow SET UserName = @UserName
               WHERE Id = @Id 
             ";

DbCommand cmd = base.Database.GetSqlStringCommand(sql);

base.Database.AddInParameter(cmd, "Id", DbType.Int32, StackOverflow.Id);
base.Database.AddInParameter(cmd, "UserName", DbType.Int32, StackOverflow.UserName);

int val = Convert.ToInt32(base.Database.ExecuteScalar(cmd));

Convert.ToInt32(base.Database.ExecuteScalar(cmd)) //returns 0.
```

I've read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

The article says:
*The function returns the new Identity column value if a new row was inserted, 0 on failure.*

but I did not insert into that table - I only want to update and return updated row Id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery) in your case.

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

> *Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query*

ExecuteNonQuery

> *Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected*

Your query doesn't return anything, so `ExecuteScalar` is not the right method to work with.
ExecuteNonQuery on the other side will give the correct information if your query has updated anything.

Answer (score -1):

If you modify your SQL statement to the following, I think this will give you the result your expecting:

```
string sql = " 
           UPDATE StackOverflow SET UserName = @UserName
           WHERE Id = @Id 

           RETURN @Id
         ";
```